# oAuth/Gmail from ASP.NET - "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request"

Tags: asp.net, oauth, google-api, google-contacts-api

I have been banging my head on this for a long time now no avail. 
Hoping some fellow SOers can help out.

1. using oAuth.net library for the Gmail Contacts API
2. The request seems well-formed and I have stepped through the requests, and cannot discern anything wrong.
3. Tried checking if the timestamp is an issue - it seems that was a common issue on the gmail forums, tried changing to various time-zones, still no luck.

   public string WebResponseGet(HttpWebRequest webRequest)
   {
       StreamReader responseReader = null;
       string responseData = "";

   ```
   try
   {
       //This is where the exception is thrown
       responseReader = new StreamReader(webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
       responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
   }
   catch (WebException ex)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(ex);
       throw;
   }
   finally
   {
       webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream().Close();
       responseReader.Close();
       responseReader = null;
   }

   return responseData;
   ```

   }

Comment: @Mikos the error must be on your WebQuest.Create (probably..) because I do not see any major problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No real responses. Shutting it down.